# How to nest routers in Go julienschmidt/httprouter?

Tags: go, httprouter

I want to expose the following URLs from my service:

```
GET /api/foo
GET /api/bar
```

I also want to structure it as a router nested inside another. The toplevel router will match all requests to `/api` and serve them with the nested router which will match requests to `/foo` and `/bar`. Basically, namespacing.

I could just have a single router and give the `/api` prefix to both the routes:

```
router.GET("/api/foo", apiFoo)
router.GET("/api/bar", apiBar)
```

But I would like the convenience of having a single router for all routes inside the `/api` prefix so that I can add appropriate middlewares to them all with a single function call.

Here's what I tried:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func apiFoo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}
func apiBar(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}

func main() {
    api := httprouter.New()
    api.HandlerFunc(http.MethodGet, "/foo", apiFoo)
    api.HandlerFunc(http.MethodGet, "/bar", apiBar)

    router := httprouter.New()
    router.Handler(http.MethodGet, "/api", api)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

However, getting 404 not found on going to http://localhost:8080/api/foo or http://localhost:8080/api/bar

I had thought that nested routers would work because routers implement the `http.Handler` interface. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe you need a trailing slash for it to be treated as a prefix and not an exact match (`router.Handler(http.MethodGet, "/api/", api)`)

Comment: @Adrian unfortunately, that didn't work, still getting 404 not found.

Comment: it does not concatenate the path, so you can't do that.  Both routers will just inspect the full request path and act accordingly. There is an open pull request since 7 years. that would implement grouping: https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/pull/89. You may be better off using chi.

Comment: @TheFool thank you. I'll look at alternatives.

Comment: @TheFool chi worked, thank you. If you want to post it as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

httprouter does not concatenate the path, so you can't do it that way. Both routers will just inspect the request path and act accordingly.

There is an [open pull request](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/pull/89) for 7 years, that would implement it. You could have a look there and implement similar logic yourself, the PR is based on concatenating the path. Maybe you can write a small helper function for that.

If you are willing to switch the router package, you could look into alternatives such as [chi](https://github.com/go-chi/chi), which support router groups.

Answer (score 0):

or use StripPrefix from the standard library

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.StripPrefix("/api", api))
```